# Error: req#login requires a callback function Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm implementing a passport reset but `req.login` doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my route

```
// Token URL :post
router.post('/users/reset/:token', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body.password === req.body['password-confirm']) {
    req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match!');
    res.redirect('/users/forgot');
  }

  User.findOne({
    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
    resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }
  }, function(err, user) {
    if(!user) {
      req.flash('error', ' Password reset is invalid or has expired');
      res.redirect(302, '/login');
    }

    const setPassword = promisify(user.setPassword, user);
    setPassword(req.body.password);
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
    const updatedUser = user.save();

    req.login(updatedUser);

    req.flash('success_msg', 'Your password has been reset successfully! You are now logged in!');
    return res.redirect('/dashboard' + req.user);
  });
});
```

and here is the logs

```
Thu Jan 25 2018 22:45:10 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/reset/3eab13651335967925c180427bfb2ccc956187be
Mongoose: users.findOne({ resetPasswordExpires: { '$gt': new Date("Thu, 25 Jan 2018 22:45:10 GMT") }, resetPasswordToken: '3eab13651335967925c180427bfb2ccc956187be' }, { fields: {} })
Thu Jan 25 2018 22:45:10 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Thu Jan 25 2018 22:45:20 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /users/reset/3eab13651335967925c180427bfb2ccc956187be
Mongoose: users.findOne({ resetPasswordExpires: { '$gt': new Date("Thu, 25 Jan 2018 22:45:20 GMT") }, resetPasswordToken: '3eab13651335967925c180427bfb2ccc956187be' }, { fields: {} })
events.js:136

      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: req#login requires a callback function
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:47:44)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/routes/users.js:326:9
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4056:16)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose `Model.save()` is asynchronous (because it takes time to get to the DB and back).  When you do the following...

```
const updatedUser = user.save();

req.login(updatedUser);
```

you are not passing the updatedUser to `req.login` - you are passing an unresolved Promise.  This is why the login function fails.  `req.login` is also asynchronous!

You need to wait for the functions to finish before using their results.  You can to this in three ways:

1) A callback function - this is what you have passed as the second argument to `User.findOne`.

```
user.save((saveError, updatedUser) => {
    // Check if saveError is present here and handle appropriately
    req.login(updatedUser, loginError => {
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Your password has been reset successfully! You are now logged in!');
        res.redirect('/dashboard' + req.user);
    })
});
```

2) Calling `.then` on the returned promise, and passing a function to `then` which will be executed when the promise resolves

```
 user.save()
     .then(updatedUser => req.login(updatedUser))
     .then(() => {
         req.flash('success_msg', 'Your password has been reset successfully! You are now logged in!');
         res.redirect('/dashboard' + req.user);
      })
      .catch(err => /* handle error */);
```

3) Using async/await and awaiting the resolution of the promise.  The whole function needs to be marked as async, then we can `await` any functions that return promises:

```
router.post('/users/reset/:token', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
      if(req.body.password === req.body['password-confirm']) {
          req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match!');
          res.redirect('/users/forgot');
      }

      const user = await User.findOne({
          resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
          resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }
      });

      if(!user) {
          req.flash('error', ' Password reset is invalid or has expired');
          res.redirect(302, '/login');
      }

      const setPassword = promisify(user.setPassword, user);
      await setPassword(req.body.password);

      user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
      user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

      const updatedUser = await user.save();

      await req.login(updatedUser);

      req.flash('success_msg', 'Your password has been reset successfully! You are now logged in!');
      return res.redirect('/dashboard' + req.user);
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried option 3 here and I get the following `SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try`

Comment: I corrected the syntax error in the answer - did you not pick this up in your code editor? The image you posted is an error related to how you are using `promisify` on `user.setPassword` - can't help with that without seeing the implementation of setPassword.

Comment: I got it  with a few tweaks.

Comment: I tried option 2 with user.create() and got this error as result: req#login requires a callback function